# PostgreSQL: Removing standby from streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4, repmgr

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 streaming replication setup between three nodes (master and two hot standbys). I use [repmgr](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr) to control the replication cluster. I need to retire one of the standbys and remove it from the replication set. I'd like to keep the data on that standby. I use replication slots.

My question is: what is the preferred way of removing a standby node from the replication set? There is a `standby unregister` command in repmgr but it will only remove the node from repmgr's catalog and won't touch the actual replication setup.